# This is my code when I insert multi record into my Collection first time it work but when i insert second time it say duplicate _id,

Tags: meteor

This is my code when I insert multi record into my Collection first time it work well but when i insert second time it say duplicate _id, how to fix it.

```
            //Save Journal Detail
            $("#item-list tr").each(function (e) {
                //debugger;
                var yearMonth = $('#journalDate').val();
                var date = moment(yearMonth).format("YYMM");
                var prefix = curBranch + "-" + date;

                var chartAccountId = $(this).find(".chart-account-id option:selected").val();
                if (chartAccountId == "" || chartAccountId == null) {
                    return;
                }
                var journalDetailId = idGenerator.genWithPrefix(Acc.Collection.JournalDetail, prefix, 8);
                var debit = parseFloat($(this).find(".debit").val());
                var credit = parseFloat($(this).find(".credit").val());
                if (debit > 0) {
                    Acc.Collection.JournalDetail.insert({
                        _id: journalDetailId,
                        journalId: doc._id,
                        chartAccountId: chartAccountId,
                        drCr: debit,
                        split: "Hello"
                    });
                } else {
                    Acc.Collection.JournalDetail.insert({
                        _id: journalDetailId,
                        journalId: doc._id,
                        chartAccountId: chartAccountId,
                        drCr: -credit,
                        split: "Hello"
                    });
                }
            });
            return doc;
```

Comment: Its better to allow Collection to insert its own _id but if you want to manually define _id, just check before the you insert. like if(!Acc.Collection.JournalDetail.findOne({_id:journalDetailId})){//insert it}

Comment: Btw where is the above code in the helpers or in the events?

Comment: I try it your solution but it now work have any help

Comment: Oh sorry it not work i confuse

Comment: whre are u writing the above code?

Comment: I write on AutoForm.hooks({
    // journal
    acc_journalInsert: {
        before: {
            insert: function (doc) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely to be that your `$.each()` iterations do not wait for your `insert` calls to finish, therefore the last id in the collection stays the same, and therefore `idGenerator.genWithPrefix` gives you the same id for multiple successive insert calls.

In the Meteor client, ["`insert` never blocks"](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert). So you would have to wait on each `insert` call before getting the next id via `idGenerator.genWithPrefix`, or else your next generated id will end up being the same as the previous one you started to insert.

One easy solution could be to transfer that logic to the server (where `insert` calls are blocking) using a method call, by only giving it the list of documents you wish for it to insert.

On the client:

```
//Save Journal Detail
var listToInsert = [];
var yearMonth = $('#journalDate').val();
var date = moment(yearMonth).format("YYMM");
var prefix = curBranch + "-" + date;
$("#item-list tr").each(function (e) {
  //debugger;
  var chartAccountId = $(this).find(".chart-account-id option:selected").val();
  if (chartAccountId == "" || chartAccountId == null) {
    return;
  }
  var debit = parseFloat($(this).find(".debit").val());
  var credit = parseFloat($(this).find(".credit").val());
  listToInsert.push({
    journalId: doc._id,
    chartAccountId: chartAccountId,
    drCr: debit > 0 ? debit : -credit, // simplified with a ternary operator
    split: "Hello"
  });
});
Meteor.call("insertEntries", listToInsert, prefix, function () {
  //done!
});
return doc;
```

On the server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'insertEntries': function (listToInsert, prefix) {
    for (var i = 0; i < listToInsert.length; i++) {
      listToInsert[i]._id = idGenerator.genWithPrefix(Acc.Collection.JournalDetail, prefix, 8);
      // Since we're on the server, this insert will be blocking
      Acc.Collection.JournalDetail.insert(listToInsert[i]);
    }
  }
});
```